# Modal View Controller with MapView And TableView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, mkmapview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm looking to replicate the basic functionality of the Stores finder in the new Starbucks app (MapView with a tableview bellow it) but am unsure as to how I would go about implementing the sliding aspect of presenting the view

[image: app example]

The main aspect of the functionality I am trying to replicate is the ability to present the modal and have it dismissible by sliding it down off the screen as I am able to replicate the Map + Table view already

Comment: Have you considered looking for a cocoaControl that do something like this? or something similar so you can modify it to your needs?

Comment: I have found a CocoaControl I'm going to use to implement the Map+Tableview functions (LocationPickerView) it is the sliding up and down ability of the view I am having the most trouble with?

Comment: @RossJ Is my answer helpful?  or do I need to expand on it?

Comment: Currently I am just presenting the view modally, however when presenting the view modally it takes up 100% of the screen. The functionality I'm looking to replicate is the ability to present the view to 70 - 85% of the screen and allow the user to drag to 100% or 0% to dismiss the view

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kipulltoreveal Just make a custom cell and you can make it identical.

Comment: I don't think this helps as the map+tableview functionality isn't the problem, it is the presenting of the Map+TableView I have problems with, I need to be able to dismiss that view by sliding it down

Answer (score 0):

Well from the Gif you posted, It seems that Starbucks just present the view controller modally which is very easy to do.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *yourVC= (YourViewController *)
                        [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourView"];
[self presentViewController:yourVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

As for dissmissing the view you would need to set `ViewController's` [interactivePopGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/interactivePopGestureRecognizer) delegate to self and then handle its behavior in [-gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

That is, when you want the built-in pop gesture ([– popViewControllerAnimated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated%3a)) to fire, you must return YES from this method. The same goes for your custom gestures - you have to figure out which recognizer you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

My thought is this is just a viewcontroller containing 2 basic views:

1. The background view including tabs and your personal info page which is below tabs.
2. A table view occupying the whole screen.

   - section 0: header: empty header / no cells
   - section 1: header: search bar / 1st cell: mapView trespassing its bounds to cover section header / other cells: locations
3. Whenever you scroll down 'too much' they defined. They do animation to hide the tableview
4. To make it looks like a modal view, they make the map corner rounded.